# Write the Statistics of the Job run to Text file in Talend

Tags: talend

I am trying to get the whole statistics of the Job Run like below and write it in a Text file

[image]

Anyone please guide me how to take this statistics, as I am running manually now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:
[image]

Use `tWarn` to log start and end of job events. Under the Job tab, go to Stats & Logs; check 'Use logs" and then "On Files" option, and specify the filepath and filename of the log file.
Make sur all the catch options are checked (they are checked by default)